# "Bookmarks are not allowed. See EDAS FAQ." help

Tags: hyperref, ieeetran

I have read all other questions with the same tags, and none of them solves my problem.

I know this is a common problem, but I am not able to find the problem.

Here is the preamble of my paper.

```
%\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{bookmarks=false}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{property}{Property}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max} %Defines a new operation argmax with no space
\usepackage[skip=5pt]{caption}   % Unifies the distance between caption and float
\usepackage[para]{footmisc} % Puts the captions side by side
%\usepackage[options]{nohyperref}  % This makes hyperref commands do nothing without errors
%\usepackage{url}
```

The thing is that I only have a url in the "thebibliography" section. This website I used to display it without using the url package, just like that:

```
\bibitem{abc} authors, ``Name,'' Nov. 2002. [Online]. Available: http://www.abc.com/file$\_$name.pdf
```

Then, as I tried the solutions in other questions, when I load the hyperref with the "bookmarks=false" option, I loaded the url package and used it with the website, and still have the problem.

I would like to add that this happened with another paper that has no url or anything that might be considered as a hyperref.

Could it be the Adobe? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for not having seen this before, but the question is unclear: what class are you using? You tagged [tag:ieeetran], but there's no mention of it in the question. Nor I can find `EDAS` in `IEEEtran.cls`, so I don't understand what software is issuing the warning/error.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @egreg: [EDAS](http://edas.info/doc/features.html) is a paper submission process.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I should add this here, or as a comment to my question.

I found a temporary solution for the problem. However, it is not a "technical" solution, as it does not explain why the problem exists in the first place.

In order to get rid of the bookmark (which is not really there) I printed my pdf using "Adobe pdf". The new generated pdf file is accepted by EDAS.